# Given a vertex and a Quaternion, calculate a vertex 3.0 in front of first

Tags: c++, math, quaternions

I have a vertex, vertC, and a Quaternion, quatC. These define the position and rotation of a camera, respectively. I need to take these and calculate a vertex, vertX, that's a distance of 3.0 away from vertC and properly rotated (i.e. it's directly in front of the camera.) How do I do this?

Comment: Are you using C++ and OpenGL or are you using Unity3D (C#)?

Comment: C++ and OpenGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prepare matrix with its translation component using x direction translation vertC.x + 3.0 , Y direction translation vertC.y + 3.0 and Z direction translation vertC.z + 3.0. Lets call this matrix with translation component as TransM.

Lets call vertex vertX before transformation as **vertX!**.
Then final after transfomation

`vertX! = quaterion * TransM * vertX`

Hope this is what you want.